# What chemical substance is obtained by dissolving C60 in olive oil?

Tags: solubility, solutions, carbon-allotropes

What chemical substance/component would be obtained of dissolving $\ce{C60}$ in olive oil? Would buckminsterfullerene (bucky-ball) change its spherical fullerene structure (soccer ball-like) into something else ($\ce{C60OO}$) or will it stay the same?

[image: Buckminsterfullerene 3D ball]

See:

- [Fullerene - Safety and toxicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene#Safety_and_toxicity) at Wikipedia
- [Fathi Moussa's experiment study on rats in 2012 which doubled their lifespan](http://www.owndoc.com/pdf/C60-Fullerene.pdf)
- [The color of the Carbon-60 in olive oil](http://c60antiaging.com/c60-faq/the-color-of-the-carbon-60-in-olive-oil/)
- [Buckminsterfullerene-olive oil production process](http://c60antiaging.com/c60-oil-production/buckybal-olive-oil-production-process/)

Comment: Dear God, fullerenes and anti-aging.  I recommend taking snake oil from the foothills of Appalachia instead.  It may not do any good, but on the other hand it does not form radical anions in the body either with no clear elimination pathway.

Comment: @AbelFriedman: C60OO toxicity experiment tested on rats by Baati showed that it is totally non-toxic and safe. So in your opinion how C60 would form radical anions in the body?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no chemical reaction between fullerene and olive oil, that is to say that the two molecules do not break or make chemical bonds to produce a new chemical species.  However, fullerene is soluble in olive oil and so there are typical solvent-solute interactions.  A homogenous solution of fullerene in olive oil produces a light purple color typical of many fullerene solutions.

[image: light purple color of fullerene solution]

Since [Moussa's 2012 experiment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22498298) where he fed fullerene in olive oil to rats and found that their life span roughly doubled, many companies have been marketing a [dark-red liquid](http://c60antiaging.com/c60-faq/the-color-of-the-carbon-60-in-olive-oil/) comprised of olive oil and fullerene.  It is likely that in many of these highly colored liquids, the fullerene is not completely dissolved and light scattering by the fine particulates are producing the observed color.

Comment: The Moussa experiment has problems, as outlined by Derek Live [here](http://pipeline.corante.com/archives/2012/04/20/buckyball_longevity_theres_a_problem.php).

Comment: Actually Lee states, "this image duplication does not directly bear on the most surprising and interesting results of the paper - life extension in rodents".  I can't say if Moussa's results are right or wrong. What I am saying is that they are very interesting and have generated a fullerene plus olive oil marketplace - buyer beware applies.

Comment: People [already consuming](http://www.longecity.org/forum/forum/415-c60health/) C60OO for few years already and nobody died yet;) Based on the [poll](http://www.longecity.org/forum/topic/58783-poll-quantifying-c60oo-data/), most of the people reporting positive experience.

Answer (score 5):

The typical reactions of C<sub>60</sub> happen at the double bond: [4+2] cycloaddition, [3+2] cycloaddition, oxidation.  Just dissolving it in olive oil (will it even go up, I know it does go up in aromatic solvent) won't do anything.